# static variable link error

Tags: c++, xcode, static-libraries, clang, static-methods

I'm writing C++ code on a mac. Why do I get this error when compiling?:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "Log::theString",
>   referenced from:
>         Log::method(std::string) in libTest.a(Log.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Not sure if my code is wrong or I have to add additional flags to Xcode. My current XCode configurations are the default ones for a 'static library' project.

My code:

Log.h------------

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Log{
public:
    static void method(string arg);
private:
    static string theString ;
};
```

Log.cpp ----

```
#include "Log.h"
#include <ostream>

void Log::method(string arg){
    theString = "hola";
    cout   << theString << endl; 
}
```

I'm calling the 'method' from a test code, in this way:
'Log::method("asd"):'

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You must define the statics in the `cpp` file.

Log.cpp

```
#include "Log.h"
#include <ostream>

string Log::theString;  // <---- define static here

void Log::method(string arg){
    theString = "hola";
    cout   << theString << endl; 
}
```

You should also remove `using namespace std;` from the header. Get into the habit while you still can. This will pollute the global namespace with `std` wherever you include the header.

Comment: Rather *initializes* instead of *defines*, no (just asking)?

Comment: Perhaps even a better term would be that it allocates space for the string.

Comment: Good point about `using namespace *;` in the header. It's easier if you shake the habit earlier on.

Comment: Just put `using namespace std;` inside your own namespace declaration :P `namespace your_custom_namespace { using namespace std; }`

Answer (score 23):

You declared `static string theString;`, but haven't defined it.

Include

```
string Log::theString;
```

to your `cpp` file