# undefined reference - each object file compiles, but link fails

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, undefined-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [static variable link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282354/static-variable-link-error)
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Sorry for adding yet another "undefined reference to" makefile problem post, but I couldn't find a solution even after extensive searching...

Each object files compiles completely fine.  During the final linking stage, the linker (or make?) complains about "undefined reference to"  various functions and static class variables...

Makefile:

```
CXX = mpic++
CXXFLAGS = -g   -O3   -fopenmp   -std=c++0x     

SOME_DIR=/some/directory

LDFLAGS=   -I$(SOME_DIR) -L$(SOME_DIR)  -Wl,-rpath,$(SOME_DIR) -lsomelib   \
             # ...more libraries...     \
           -Wl,--verbose    -ldl


SOURCES=$(wildcard ./*.cpp)
HEADERS=$(wildcard ./*.h)

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)


all :   $(OBJECTS)  
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)   $(LDFLAGS)      \
    -o my_prog
    @echo "my_prof executable successfully created."

%.o  :  %.cpp   $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@  -c    $(LDFLAGS)   $<
```

All "include guards" are in place for each `.h` file.  Each object file compiles without issue.  Examining the extra output provided form the linker via `--verbose`, I verify that all libraries linked to are found by the linker, and that all object files are successfully opened by the linker.

Then, at the last stage, I get a slew of  "undefined references" to functions in *other* source/object files:

```
./some_object.o: In function `some_class::some_func(int &arg)':
./some_class.cpp:78: undefined reference to 'another_function_defined_in_another_header_file'
```

And also undefined references to  (public) static member variables :

```
./main.cpp:473: undefined reference to `some_class::some_static_member_variable_A'
./main.cpp:491: undefined reference to `some_class::some_static_member_variable_B'
./main.cpp:500: undefined reference to `some_class::some_static_member_variable_C'
./main.cpp:511: undefined reference to `some_class::some_static_member_variable_D'
```

Comment: post your source code, seems more than a linker error to me OR a short source code that summerizes it.

Comment: @Aniket but each individual object file compiles correctly... so doesn't that rule out the source code?

Comment: You declared the variable but didn't define it.

Comment: no @MatthewParks it doesn't. Static variables are local to the file.. can't be accessed from outside the file

Comment: @Aniket wrong kind of `static`, this `static` means the `static` member of a class.