# OpenGL XCode8 Linking Error

Tags: opengl, xcode8, glfw, glew, macos-sierra

I have a problem building my OpenGL project.

I'm getting the following error.

```
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have "Other Linker Flags" set to "-lGLEW"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this somehow fixed my problem :D

[static variable link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282354/static-variable-link-error)

The problem i wasn't define the static fields in the translation file.