# ERROR of "undefined reference" in JVM 9 when I invoke a self-defined member function in "class os"

Tags: java, c++, linux, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I am hacking [JVM9 source code](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev), especially [`class os` part](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/os.hpp#L88).

What I am trying to do is:

(1) add a `static int` array named `gc_tid[64]` to store some thread id information.

(2) add a `static int nr_gc_tid;` to count the number of threads above

So, I only add another two members in `class os` [here](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/os.hpp#L102), similar to the previous variable member
[`static size_t             _page_sizes[page_sizes_max];`](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/os.hpp#L101).

(Everything I did here is to mimic how `_page_sizes` is declared in `os.hpp`)

```
class os: AllStatic {
    public:
    ...
    static int  gc_tid[64];
    static int nr_gc_tid;
    ...
};
```

I also have to do initialization of both `nr_gc_tid` and `gc_tid[64]`.

So, I write a `static void init_gc_tid(void)` in
`hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/os.hpp`  before [here](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/os.hpp#L103) as a `public` member function.

```
static void init_gc_tid(void);
```

Then, I define this function `init_gc_tid(void)` in `hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp` just before [`void os::init(void)`](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#L4717) (Everything I did here is to mimic how `os::init(void)` is declared in `os.hpp` , and is defined in `os_linux.cpp`)

```
void os::init_gc_tid(void){
  //step 1: init nr_gctid as 0
  nr_gc_tid = 0;
  //step 2: init all gc tid as -100
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 64; ++i){
    gc_tid[i] = -100;
  }
}
```

Finally, I call my `init_gc_tid` function in `os::init(void)` after `init_page_sizes((size_t) Linux::page_size());` [here](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/master/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#L4732).

But it doesn't work. When I `make` the JVM9 project. I get errors like

```
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Compiling 11 properties into resource bundles for java.logging
Compiling 3 files for COMPILE_CREATE_SYMBOLS
Compiling 11 properties into resource bundles for jdk.management.agent
Compiling 3 properties into resource bundles for jdk.jdi
Compiling 2 files for BUILD_BREAKITERATOR_BASE
Compiling 11 properties into resource bundles for jdk.jartool
Compiling 2 files for BUILD_BREAKITERATOR_LD
Compiling 4 properties into resource bundles for jdk.jlink
Compiling 3 properties into resource bundles for jdk.jlink
Compiling 1 properties into resource bundles for jdk.jlink
Compiling 224 properties into resource bundles for jdk.localedata
Creating buildtools/jdk.vm.compiler.replacements.verifier.jar
Compiling 6 properties into resource bundles for java.base
Compiling 11 properties into resource bundles for java.base
Creating ct.sym classes
Creating buildtools/jdk.vm.compiler.match.processor.jar
Creating support/symbols/ct.sym
Compiling 100 properties into resource bundles for java.desktop
Compiling 2897 files for java.base
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/os_linux.o: In function `os::init_gc_tid()':
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:4726: undefined reference to `os::nr_gc_tid'
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:4730: undefined reference to `os::gc_tid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/support/modules_libs/java.base/server/libjvm.so] Error 1
lib/CompileJvm.gmk:207: recipe for target '/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/support/modules_libs/java.base/server/libjvm.so' failed
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/os_linux.o: In function `os::init_gc_tid()':
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:4726: undefined reference to `os::nr_gc_tid'
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:4730: undefined reference to `os::gc_tid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
lib/CompileGtest.gmk:64: recipe for target '/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/gtest/libjvm.so' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/gtest/libjvm.so] Error 1
make/Main.gmk:263: recipe for target 'hotspot-server-libs' failed
make[2]: *** [hotspot-server-libs] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

ERROR: Build failed for target 'default (exploded-image)' in configuration 'linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug' (exit code 2) 
Stopping sjavac server

=== Output from failing command(s) repeated here ===
* For target hotspot_variant-server_libjvm_gtest_objs_BUILD_GTEST_LIBJVM_link:
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/os_linux.o: In function `os::init_gc_tid()':
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:4726: undefined reference to `os::nr_gc_tid'
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:4730: undefined reference to `os::gc_tid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
* For target hotspot_variant-server_libjvm_objs_BUILD_LIBJVM_link:
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/objs/os_linux.o: In function `os::init_gc_tid()':
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:4726: undefined reference to `os::nr_gc_tid'
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp:4730: undefined reference to `os::gc_tid'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

* All command lines available in /home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/make-support/failure-logs.
=== End of repeated output ===

=== Make failed targets repeated here ===
lib/CompileJvm.gmk:207: recipe for target '/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/support/modules_libs/java.base/server/libjvm.so' failed
lib/CompileGtest.gmk:64: recipe for target '/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/gtest/libjvm.so' failed
make/Main.gmk:263: recipe for target 'hotspot-server-libs' failed
=== End of repeated output ===

Hint: Try searching the build log for the name of the first failed target.
Hint: If caused by a warning, try configure --disable-warnings-as-errors.

/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/make/Init.gmk:291: recipe for target 'main' failed
make[1]: *** [main] Error 2
/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/make/Init.gmk:185: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

### I highlight the error part:

> undefined reference to `os::nr_gc_tid'
>
> undefined reference to `os::gc_tid'

Comment: This is a classic error that happens because static data members are *declarations*, not *definitions*. Look up “static data member linker error” and you’ll likely get a very quick fix.

Comment: @templatetypedef forgive me and I just don't know how to fix even if I look up other posts in stackoverflow, like `What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?` Please give me more instructions, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post helps,
[static variable link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282354/static-variable-link-error)

add

```
int os:: gc_tid[64];
int os:: nr_gc_tid;
```

at the beginning of `os_linux.cpp` file